# Combine 2 separate database queries in one foreach loop or combine queries into one

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have this query to check the last 3 months sales figures and another query to check the refund figures. I would like to display them in a table like:

Sept    $100   $20
Aug      $200    $10
Jul        $150    $0

But, I am not sure if it would be better to try combine the 2 queries into one. I tried to put a foreach loop for refunds inside the sales foreach loop but that resulted in 6 rows instead of 3.

```
       // sales
        SELECT DATE_FORMAT(order_date, '%b') as month, SUM(order_total) as totalSales FROM
        (
           SELECT order_date, order_total
           FROM order_summary
           WHERE order_date <= NOW()
           and order_date >= Date_add(Now(),interval - 3 month)
           AND `order_status` = 'Approved'

           UNION ALL
           SELECT  Date_add(Now(),interval - 2 month)  AS order_date, 0 as order_total
           UNION ALL
           SELECT  Date_add(Now(),interval - 1 month)   AS order_date, 0 as order_total
           UNION ALL
           SELECT  Now() AS order_date, 0 as order_total
        ) as test
        GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(order_date, '%m-%Y')
        ORDER BY DATE_FORMAT(order_date, '%m-%Y') DESC

      // refunds
    SELECT DATE_FORMAT(credit_date, '%b') as month, SUM(`credit_value`) as totalCredit FROM
        (
           SELECT credit_value, credit_date
           FROM credit
           WHERE credit_date <= NOW()
           and credit_date >= Date_add(Now(),interval - 3 month)
           AND `reason` = 'Refund'

           UNION ALL
           SELECT  Date_add(Now(),interval - 2 month)  AS credit_date, 0 as credit_value
           UNION ALL
           SELECT  Date_add(Now(),interval - 1 month)   AS credit_date, 0 as credit_value
           UNION ALL
           SELECT  Now() AS credit_date, 0 as credit_value
        ) as test
        GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(credit_date, '%m-%Y')
        ORDER BY DATE_FORMAT(credit_date, '%m-%Y') DESC
        ");
```

***UPDATE AFTER O. Jones ANSWER***

```
 SELECT a.month, a.totalSales, b.totalCredit
 FROM (SELECT DATE_FORMAT(order_date, '%b') as month, SUM(order_total) as totalSales, DATE(DATE_FORMAT(order_date, '%Y-%m-01')) month_starting FROM
        (
           SELECT order_date, order_total
           FROM order_summary
           WHERE order_date <= NOW()
           and order_date >= Date_add(Now(),interval - 3 month)
           AND `order_status` = 'Approved'

           UNION ALL
           SELECT  Date_add(Now(),interval - 2 month)  AS order_date, 0 as order_total
           UNION ALL
           SELECT  Date_add(Now(),interval - 1 month)   AS order_date, 0 as order_total
           UNION ALL
           SELECT  Now() AS order_date, 0 as order_total
        ) as test
        GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(order_date, '%m-%Y')
        ORDER BY DATE_FORMAT(order_date, '%m-%Y') DESC) a
 JOIN (         SELECT DATE_FORMAT(credit_date, '%b') as month, SUM(`credit_value`) as totalCredit, DATE(DATE_FORMAT(credit_date, '%Y-%m-01')) month_starting FROM
            (
               SELECT credit_value, credit_date
               FROM credit
               WHERE credit_date <= NOW()
               and credit_date >= Date_add(Now(),interval - 3 month)
               AND `reason` = 'Refund'

               UNION ALL
               SELECT  Date_add(Now(),interval - 2 month)  AS credit_date, 0 as credit_value
               UNION ALL
               SELECT  Date_add(Now(),interval - 1 month)   AS credit_date, 0 as credit_value
               UNION ALL
               SELECT  Now() AS credit_date, 0 as credit_value
            ) as test
            GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(credit_date, '%m-%Y')
            ORDER BY DATE_FORMAT(credit_date, '%m-%Y') desc ) b ON a.month_starting = b.month_starting
ORDER BY a.month_starting
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a job for a join. You want one row per month showing the month, the orders, and the credits. Because the orders and credits come from different queries, you join them together to get this.

First add `DATE(DATE_FORMAT(order_date, '%Y-%m-01')) month_starting`  to your first query's SELECT, and `DATE(DATE_FORMAT(credit_date, '%Y-%m-01')) month_starting`to your second query's SELECT.

Then wrap your two queries in an outer query with a JOIN, like this.

```
 SELECT a.month, a.totalSales, b.totalCredit
 FROM ( your first query ) a
 JOIN ( your second query ) b ON a.month_starting = b.month_starting
ORDER BY month_starting
```

The trick is to understand that *queries can be used as if they were tables* by wrapping them in  `(query) alias`

Comment: Thank you, there is too much code to paste in here so I have edited my original question. The first error that the GROUP BY was ambiguous so I just changed it to a.month_starting. No errors after that but it is only showing one row and not 3?